# Angular async parameter in template statement

Tags: angular, event-binding

I'm currently having a hard time trying to figure out how to use async parameter in a template statement while doing event binding.

I've tried the following snippet:

```html
<div (click)="goToProfile((user|async)?.id)"></div>
```

and it fails with

> ng: Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 20 in [goToProfile((user|async)?.id)] in @2:19 ng: The pipe '' could not be found

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ng: Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 20 in [goToProfile((user|async)?.id)] in @2:19 ng: The pipe '' could not be found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
<div *ngIf="user | async as u" (click)="goToProfile(u.id)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's telling you that you cannot use a pipe on a parameter passed into a function.

you would have to do do something like

```
{{ user | async }}
```

or

```
goToProfile(user ? user.id : null)
```

if you're just trying to wait for the object to be populated, maybe something like

```
<div *ngIf="user">
    <div (click)="goToProfile(user.id)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but its not true its observable i need async pipe

Comment: what are you trying to async when the user is present you want to use the id?